# How to change Angular service injection instance

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, inject

Hi im trying to change an injected service instance of a component tree (a parent e.g. `ParentComponent` and a few children e.g. `Child1Component`,`Child2Component`) that all depend on a service called `DataService`. But depending on the route, like `/demo`, I want to inject to `ParentComponent` and its children another service instance (it would be derived from an interface/abstract class, that's not the problem) and WITHOUT changing the internal implementations of `ParentComponent` or `Child1Component` or `Child2Component` have them use the `MockDataService` constructor injected service.

Any thoughts? I need something that can change the injection on the fly without a factory method I think.

```js
abstract class AbstractDataService {}

@Inject()
class DataService extends AbstractDataService {}

@Inject()
class MockDataService extends AbstractDataService {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root'
  template: '<app-parent></app-parent>'
})
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt: NavigationStart) => {
      if (evt.url === '/demo') { // something like that or do it in router config...
        // TODO change the injection instance here for ParentComponent and children...
      }
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<app-child1></app-child1> <app-child2></app-child2>'
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private data: AbstractDataService) { }
  // ...
}


@Component({...})
class Child1Component {
  constructor(private data: AbstractDataService) { }
  // ...
}


@Component({...})
class Child2Component {
  constructor(private data: AbstractDataService) { }
  // ...
}
```

(I'm using Angular 10 btw)

Answer (score 1):

If you got no state management and want no factory, maybe you can make a Service than rules them all, you can improve the way with rxjs BehaviorSubject

```
abstract class AbstractDataService {}

@Inject()
class DataService extends AbstractDataService {}

@Inject()
class MockDataService extends AbstractDataService {}

@Inject({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class DataStoreService {

service = this.dataService;

constructor(private dataService: DataService, private mockDataService: MockDataService){}

useDemoService(){
  this.service = this.mockDataService;
}

useRealDataService(){
  this.service = this.dataService;
}

anyMethod(){
return this.service.getAnyValue();
}

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root'
  template: '<app-parent></app-parent>'
})
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private dataStoreService: DataStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((evt: NavigationStart) => {
      if (evt.url === '/demo') {
       dataStoreService.useDemoService();
      }else{
       dataStoreService.useRealDataService()
      }
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<app-child1></app-child1> <app-child2></app-child2>'
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private data: DataStoreService) { }
  // ...
}


@Component({...})
class Child1Component {
  constructor(private data: DataStoreService) { }
  // ...
}


@Component({...})
class Child2Component {
  constructor(private data: DataStoreService) { }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That's a good workaround. I'm not against factory but I don't know if it will do what I want. I'm looking for undocumented framework knowledge about `Injector` and what not. Else I could pepper if statements all over and be done.